# ArrayAdapter: What is the best way to approach creating an ArrayAdapter that would display the text from the toString() method of a custom type?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I was going to create an ArrayList of GPS coordinates that are saved in a custom object. I then want to display a list of these GPS coordinates. My current solution is to create a parallel ArrayList of strings that essentially are the GPS.toString() results.

This seems like a complicated bit of extra work that might be able to be avoided and simplified. Can anybody think of a better way to do this that doesn't require an awkwardly large amount of work. I looked a little into creating a custom ArrayAdapter but I'm not sure I fully understand how to convert the GPS coordinate object into something useful for the ListView. If you think this is a better solution, could you perhaps give a little insight into how to use this properly? (even if it's just a link)

Thanks in advance!
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want something fancy to show along those coordinates maybe you should stick with the default ArrayAdapter supplied with the ArrayList of your GPS.toString().

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you override the toString() method in the custom object, then just iterate over them from your array?

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return "Latitude: " + this.latitude; //....;
}
```

Comment: was already doing that, hence the proposal of a second ArrayList